# Loading itemTemplate for WinJS.UI.ListView from external source

Tags: winjs, windows-8.1

I am wondering if someone can shed some light on why this does not work.

I can successfully dynamically template each WinJS.UI.ListView item if I define the templates in my html view (First Scenario). However if I load the template from a seperate html file using a $.get statement it does not work (Second Scenario).

`self.selectTemplate = function (itemPromise) {
    return itemPromise.then(function (item) { ...`

First Scenario:

```
(var itemTemplate = document.getElementById(item.data.controlType + "ItemTemplate");

var container = document.createElement("div");

itemTemplate.winControl.render(item.data, container);

return container;)
```

Second Scenario:

```
(var itemTemplatePromise = ko.bindingHandlers.searchPropertyBuilder.loadTemplate(item.data.controlType);

itemTemplatePromise.done(function (itemTemplateLoaded) {

var templateContainer = document.createElement("div");

    templateContainer.innerHTML = itemTemplateLoaded;
    templateElement = templateContainer.firstChild; 

    WinJS.UI.process(templateElement);

    var container = document.createElement("div");
    templateElement.winControl.render(item.data, container);
    return container;
});)

}

WinJS.Utilities.markSupportedForProcessing(self.selectTemplate);

WinJS.Namespace.define("TemplateSelector", {

    template: self.selectTemplate
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see one bug in the code. but not sure if that is the only issue here. promises needs to be chained. winjs.ui.processAll returns a promise.

```
itemTemplatePromise.then(function (itemTemplateLoaded) {

  var templateContainer = document.createElement("div");
  templateContainer.innerHTML = itemTemplateLoaded;
  templateElement = templateContainer.firstChild; 

  return WinJS.UI.processAll(templateElement);
}).then(function onprocessall()
{
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    templateElement.winControl.render(item.data, container);
    return container;
});
```